# submodules dependency graph

Tags: java, maven, graph, diagram

I need to generate a dependency graph for my java application but only for sub-modules and not the plugins.

Example in pom.xml

```
 <modules>
        <module>module1/pom1.xml</module>
        <module>module2/pom2.xml/module>
 </modules>
```

I tried depgraph with graphviz but it generates the plugins dependencies and not the sub-modules, any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need it to be graphical? If not, `mvn dependency:tree` is a standard way for generating dependencies graph, using Maven 2 resolution however. Look at this: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks Michal,The thing is that i want only the submodules and not the jars.

Comment: Not the jars? What does it actually mean? You want to exclude all artifacts with type of `jar`?

Comment: You mean the modules itself ? (Furthermore you shouldn't write pom.xml in your module entries. And definitely not pom1.xml etc.)

Comment: yes , i want the modules itself , in the draw it should be like : parent -> Module 1 -> Module 11  and so on ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly i found the solution using depgraph plugin , its to a apply a filter in its configuration like this :

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>ch.elca.el4j.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-depgraph-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>           
                 <groupFilter>com.stackoverflow.*</groupFilter>                            
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
```

this will draw all draw all dependencies starting with "com.stackoverflow" , in my case they are submodules.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had to manually adjust the dependency *javax.inject:inject:1.0* to *javax.inject:javax.inject:1* in the module-core pom of the plugin but it works really well. Thanks for this

Comment: I'm guessing this has to do with encountering the following error when you executed `mvn depgraph:depgraph`:


`[ERROR] ... 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.inject:inject:jar:1.0: Could not transfer artifact javax.inject:inject:pom:1.0 from/to el4jRepositoryInternal (http://public-el4.elca-services.ch/el4j-protected/maven2repository/): Not authorized. -> [Help 1]`

How did you tweak the pom?

Comment: @FatuHoku modify the file module-core-3.1.pom under `~/.m2/repository/ch/elca/el4j/modules/module-core/3.1` so it contains: `<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

You could give the [maven graph plugin](http://mvnplugins.fusesource.org/maven/1.0/maven-graph-plugin/index.html) a try. It can draw a dependency graph with a transitivity depth of 1.
This will not guarantee you that no additional noise, dependencies which are not sub-modules, will be drawn.

The other option is to use the [graphiz maven plgin](http://graphviz-maven-plugin.bryon.us/dot-mojo.html) and create your own *dot* file.

Comment: Doesn't really work for me. I've got `dot` installed and ready on PATH as well.